# Using the g++ compiler in VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++, mingw, codeblocks

I am running Codeblocks on Windows 10 and using the g++ compiler. I would like to start using VS Code for C++ development and installed the C++ extension. How can I set up VS Code to use the g++ compiler, or do I need to install Mingw for VS Code?

Comment: You should install msys2 and use the mingw that is included with that instead of the old version of mingw that is bundled with Code::Blocks. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2) The official VSCode suggests that you do that: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: Make sure you pay attention to this part of the documentation: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson) I assume if you are not new to coding you will have c++ projects with more than 1 source file.